# ng add angular material results in peer dependency error

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, electron

I'm working on an electron app that uses angular 13 and angular materials. I now want to use this boiler plate code (notice branch number) so I cloned this branch:

https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/tree/angular13

After running "npm install", I then run "ng add @angular/material@13.3.9" to installed angular material. I end up with this error:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (14.2.5) is greater than your local version (13.3.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
i Using package manager: npm
√ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/material@13.3.9 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-electron@10.5.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@13.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"13.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.3.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"14.2.5" from @angular/animations@14.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.3.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\maat0001\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\maat0001\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-11T12_15_01_176Z-debug-0.log
× Package install failed, see above.
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Any suggestions, please?

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-electron",
  "version": "10.5.2",
  "description": "Angular 13 with Electron 18 (Typescript + SASS + Hot Reload)",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron",
  "author": {
    "name": "Maxime GRIS",
    "email": "maxime.gris@gmail.com"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular 13",
    "electron",
    "electron 18",
    "nodejs",
    "typescript",
    "playwright",
    "eslint",
    "sass",
    "windows",
    "mac",
    "linux"
  ],
  "main": "app/main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p electron:serve ng:serve",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve -c web -o",
    "build": "npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build --base-href ./",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "web:build": "npm run build -- -c web-production",
    "electron": "electron",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on tcp:4200 && npm run electron:serve-tsc && electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && electron .",
    "electron:build": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --publish=never",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "test:watch": "ng test",
    "e2e": "npm run build:prod && playwright test -c e2e/playwright.config.ts e2e/",
    "e2e:show-trace": "playwright show-trace e2e/tracing/trace.zip",
    "version": "conventional-changelog -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r 0 && git add CHANGELOG.md",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "13.3.1",
    "rxjs": "7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
    "@playwright/test": "1.20.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.10.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "17.0.23",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.17.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "2.2.2",
    "electron": "18.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "22.14.13",
    "electron-debug": "3.2.0",
    "electron-reloader": "1.2.3",
    "eslint": "8.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "38.1.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.17",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-electron": "7.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "playwright": "1.20.2",
    "ts-node": "10.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "wait-on": "6.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "chrome 100"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Add the `--force` flag when you run the ng add.

Comment: Same problem unfortunately. Same with --legacy-peer-deps